# Trigger that only runs runs once per day

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

This trigger backs up data from dbo.node to dbo.nodearchive. While backups are important, I only need to do this once per day. Note that there is a field called dbo.NodeArchive.versionDate (smalldDatetime).

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Node_update] 
ON  [dbo].[Node]
for UPDATE

AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.NodeArchive ([NodeID]
  ,[ParentNodeID]
  ,[Slug]
  ,[xmlTitle]
...    
  ,[ModifyBy]
  ,[ModifyDate]
  ,[CreateBy]
  ,[CreateDate])

SELECT [deleted].[NodeID]
  ,[deleted].[ParentNodeID]
  ,[deleted].[Slug]
  ,[deleted].[xmlTitle]
...  
  ,[deleted].[ModifyBy]
  ,[deleted].[ModifyDate]
  ,[deleted].[CreateBy]
  ,[deleted].[CreateDate]
FROM  [deleted] LEFT JOIN dbo.Node
ON  [deleted].NodeID = dbo.Node.NodeID
WHERE deleted.ModifyDate <> dbo.Node.ModifyDate
END
GO
```

I am looking to backup changes, but never more than one backup version per day. If there is no change, there is no backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a *trigger* anymore - that'll be a **scheduled job**. Triggers by their very definition execute *whenever* a given operation (`INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE`) happens.

Use the SQL Server Agent facility to schedule that T-SQL code to run once per day.

Read [all about SQL Server Agent Jobs in the SQL Server Books Online on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)

**Update:** so if I understand correctly: you want to have an `UPDATE` trigger - but that trigger would only record the `NodeID` that were affected, into a "these nodes need to be backed up at night" sort of table. Then, at night, you would have a SQL Agent Job that runs and that scans that "work table" and for all `NodeID` values stored in there, it would then execute that T-SQL statement to copy their data into the `NodeArchive` table.

With this approach, if your nodes with `NodeID = 42` changes ten times, you'll still only have a single entry `NodeID = 42` in your work table, and the nightly backup job would then copy that node only once into the `NodeArchive`.

With this approach, you can *decouple* the actual copying (which might take time) from the update process. The `UPDATE` trigger only records which `NodeID` rows need processing - the actual processing then happens sometime later, at an off-peak hour, without disturbing users of your system.

Comment: When there is an update to dbo.Node it should insert into dbo.NodeArchive. If a particular row in dbo.Node never changes, dbo.NodeArchive never has anything inserted.